# How to manage configuration based on build type and build flavor

Tags: android, android-build-flavors, android-flavors, android-buildconfig

In my app I have 2 build types `release` and `debug`, below is the code snippet.

```
buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix = ".debug"
        buildConfigField("boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true")
    }

    getByName("release") {
        proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        buildConfigField("boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "false")
    }
}
```

and I also have 2 product flavors below is the code snippet.

```
flavorDimensions("version")
productFlavors {
    create("flavor1") {
        setDimension("version")
    }
    create("flavor2") {
        setDimension("version")
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
}
```

Now in total I have 4 product types

- flavor1debug
- flavor1release
- flavor2debug
- flavor2release

Now I need to create a variable app_name so that the app name can be different for different product types.

- flavor1debug  ---------> app_name : flavor1 (debug)
- flavor1release  ---------> app_name : flavor1
- flavor2debug  ---------> app_name : flavor2 (debug)
- flavor2release  ---------> app_name : flavor2

How do I achieve the same using configuration or strings.xml

**Edit:** Let's assume, I am using a third party library and I want to use different authentication key, how can I achieve this using `Flavor` & `buildType` combination?

i.e I need 4 different keys based on following configuration

1. Flavor1 + debug ========= Key1
2. Flavor1 + release ========= Key2
3. Flavor2 + debug =========== Key3
4. Flavor2 + release ========== Key4

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Declare strings.xml in every source set and then you can put different values for different build type and flavor check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets)

Comment: resValue() should be in buildType and productFlavors, so total 4 places the resValue() would be written correct?

Comment: @DisplayName yes

Comment: I can't do this since I won't be knowing if there is a debug build type does it belong to FlavorA or FlavorB

Comment: Alternatively, you can create separate string.xml file in each resource set and you can declare whatever strings there check, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,


productFlavors {
   flavorA {
        setDimension("version")
        manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel : "FlavourA"]

    }
   flavorB {
        setDimension("version")
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appLabel : "FlavourB"]

    }
}


In android manifest file set this appLabel.

 <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_launcher"
        android:label="${appLabel}"    // Add this line.
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
/>
```

Comment: This won't work, how you would be tackling the buildType in this case?